# UIImagePicker URL convert for attributesOfItemAtPath iOS

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I've been trying to figure out how to convert a "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" into a path that I can use to call the "attributesOfItemAtPath" method of the NSFileManager class.

I tried [NSURL path], but it doesn't convert it into a directory path that the NSFileManager can understand...

Is there some way to do this, or maybe another way of getting the *actual* path of the file picked with UIImagePicker?

Comment: What info are you trying to get?

Comment: Mainly FileSize, FileName, DateCreated, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get is an Assets Library URL. You can use this to get the [`asset`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/ALAsset) object which you can use to gather relevant information.

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:theAssetURL
         resultBlock:^(ALAsset * asset) {
                /* Use the "asset" object to get the details */
            }
        failureBlock:^(NSError * error) {
                /* Error retrieving the asset */
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }];
```

You can look at the `valueForKey:` and `defaultRepresentation` methods.